# Upload files using umbraco data type

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I want to create a custom data type or better reuse an existing one that allows me to upload a file (pdfs or images) on a specific folder (in an Umbraco 7 site) not related to media folder. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a new property editor ([Tutorial](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/)) to create the view of the datatype and let the angular code call a UmbracoAuthorizedApiController ([Documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/)) to do the uploading of the file

Comment: I am trying to avoid this for due to budget constraints.